# socket.io doesn't work for very first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

In my express's route I do this

```
var cookie = require('cookie');
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function(client) {

    console.log('socket connected') // returned socket connected

    if(client.request.headers.cookie){
        console.log(userId) //returned userId
        var userId = cookie.parse(client.request.headers.cookie).userId;
        client.on('call_'+userId, function(data) {
            io.emit('call_'+userId,data); 
        });
    }


});

router.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
     }else{
        res.locals.username = req.user.username;

        //set cookie for socket.io purposes
        if(!cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).userId){
            res.cookie('userId',querystring.escape(req.user._id));
        }

        return next();
     }
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('./dashboard');
});
```

and I try to do an emit to port 5000, it worked. But it only work after I refresh the page after login, it doesn't work when I first come to dashboard's page. I've tried to see if the socket is connected upon login, and I did see it's connected.

Why it only for after I refresh? What's the issue?

Comment: Could you include some of  your client-side code as well?

Comment: @RobinDardelet my cilent side code has no problem at all.

Comment: @Maria Jane But it can help to help you.

Comment: @RomainIsnel solved, thanks for the hint, haha! I use localstorage and it need delay to get the value.